# Price more than 100 million

Tags: magento-1.9, price

How to set a price more than 100 million? Tried this solution http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/210738/P15/#t454441, but no luck.
Now I can set price more than 100 million, but on the frontend it automatically converts to 100 million special price.
If changing values in DB directly, everything fine, before you make changes in admin panel.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain in details what exactly is the problem? Because I only changed DB table catalog_product_entity_decimal -> column value to decimal(24,4) and nothing else (no files) and I'm able to save the product with 100000000 price and it's showing 100,000,000.00 price on frontend (i.e. it's okay). I didn't make an order but as far as I understand you the problem is in product view page.

Comment: 100 million is the maximum price. If set product price for 150 million, it showed like 150 million crossed and 100 million special price. In DB price saving like 100 million.

Comment: Aha, sorry, it's clear now. Please see my answer. I tested it on clear Magento 1.9.0.1 installation and it's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change **`value`** column in database table `catalog_product_entity_decimal`. Also you have to change all **price** columns in these tables: `catalog_product_index_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, forgot about table <catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp>.

Answer (score 0):

Export your database, edit your sql file using text editor like sublime or atom or etc that can find and replace text. Search for decimal(12,4) and replaced it with decimal(13,4), 13&12 means how much number you will save in database colum structure including 4 decimal places. Then finally you can import your database.